# Display all product in sale report

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

in sale report you can choose only products and quantity bought per costumers and export it as an excel file 
what i need is a way to show all products even if the quantity is 0

Is that possible ? 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to change the join type to left join.

Comment: It's already left join

Answer (score 0):

you can using the advanced filters in the search bar
chose quantity on hand equal 0 or greater than 0

Comment: There is no quantity on hand filter in sale.report